# Select specific node just after a specific node using Xpath

Tags: xpath

I want to select `<space/>` nodes which are just after `<link>` node using XPath.

Input :

```
<p>A.<space/>Olson,<c>1</c>
    <link>
        <context>
            <image/>
        </context><space/>
    </link><space/>W. M.<space/>Sischo,<c>1</c>
    <link>
        <context>
            <image/>
        </context><space/>
    </link><space/>A. C. B.<space/>Berge,<c>2</c>
    <link>
        <context>
            <image/>
        </context><space/>
    </link><space/>A.<space/>Adams-Progar,<c>3</c>
    <link>
        <context>
            <image/>
        </context><space/>
    </link>and<space/> D. A.<space/>Moore <space/><c>1</c> * 
    <link>
        <context>
            <image/>
        </context><space/>
    </link>
</p>
```

I want to select all `<space>` node just after `<link>` node. There are 3 nodes like that. There is a another `<space>` node after `<link>` node. But there is text as `and` before `<space>` node. such  node should not be selected.

Tried Xpath:

```
space[preceding-sibling::link]
```

When using above Xpath, select all `<space>` nodes. Help me to solve this.

Comment: Please try xpath `//link/space`. Here, `//link` will give you all the links and `/space` will give you the space tags following the link tag.

Comment: @PRERNAPAL Actually I don't need to select `<space>` nodes inside <link>.

Comment: My apologies. I misunderstood the question. Please try this xpath:
`//space/preceding-sibling::link`

Comment: @PRERNAPAL This also not working friend

Comment: could you share the output please?

Answer (score 0):

After running into something similar myself, I think this expression should do it:

```
//link[following-sibling::space[1][not(preceding-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space(self::text())])]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath-1.0 expression

```
//space[preceding-sibling::node()[1] = preceding-sibling::link[1]]/following::text()[1]
```

Its output is:

```
W. M.
A. C. B.
A.
```